# how to get the mutual relationship between users in Django ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Sorry I'm writing this question from mobile so couldn't provide the real code but

I have a relationship model with following many to many with related name followers

I wanna write a model manager function that returns all mutual relationship that is the people I'm following who happens to be my followers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a model like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    following = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', related_name='followed_by')
```

A given `Profile` object `p` would access all of its followers through `p.following.all()`. It would access all profiles that follow it through `p.followed_by.all()`.

With that in mind, you can access all of the profiles `p` follows that are following `p` with:

```
p.following.filter( id__in = p.followed_by.all() )
```

Comment: Thanks so much _in just completely passed by my mind thanks again

Comment: how to check if requested user in those all following users?